# How can I setup up DNS using Google?

Tags: apache2, dns, bind, domain-server

I'm REALLY struggling with this, I've been trying for the past two hours to figure this out, I've looked through various tutorials and similar questions but none of them have assisted me.

I have a domain example.net hosted with XYZ provider, and I have a VPS hosted with ABC provider. The VPS has a single static IPv4 address, when I visit this IP in my browser I see the default Apache webpage, all good there.

How can I make it so that when users visit example.net they see the site?

I wish to use the Google Public DNS (IPs 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4). All the guides I find start referring to "server names" and things I don't appear to have. I know I need to use BIND somehow, trust me I've been through every guide possible and I'm no closer to understanding.

Could I get some guidance please?

Comment: I was at the same level before reading this guide.It has conceptual and deployment knowledge with a series of tutorials. Your problem will get solved by one of the DNS type mentioned there.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorial_series/an-introduction-to-managing-dns

Comment: Don't feel bad, DNS systems are pretty complex!

Comment: Please see my comment on user4556274's answer.

Comment: And I know this is a whole different matter, but you need to think about if you will be able to adequately secure your server. Leaving `/var/www/html`  with file permissions of `777` is a common newbie mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Your XYZ provider will (very likely) have a web page or other configuration interface which will allow you to create an IPv4 address record (`A` record) to map the domain you lease via XYZ to the IPv4 address of your VPS.

Log on to your account at XYZ and search "DNS" there.  Since every registrar lays their website out differently, you'll have to either share who XYZ is and hope someone using the same registrar can give you specific instructions, or search there on your own.  If XYZ does *not* provide DNS service at no additional cost for domains it administers, find a new provider.

> I wish to use the Google Public DNS (IPs 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4).

Once you configure your `A` record with XYZ (or another DNS provider of your choice), it will be available via any DNS server; you don't need to ask your users to configure a *specific* DNS server in order to obtain the correct IPv4 address.

In theory, it can take up to 48 hours for a new entry to propagate from the DNS server on which it is configured to all other DNS servers, although you won't see this kind of delay if `example.com` is a newly configured domain, rather than one where you are merely reconfiguring it and existing cached records may exist on other servers.

Comment: To add just a bit: You can't use Google's DNS for what you are trying to do. What you'll probably want to do is to have the DNS hosting with the same provider as the VPS. For example, I run an Amazon EC2 VPS webserver, and have the DNS hosted with Route53. It makes your life so much easier!

Comment: And to the author of this post: Might want to add that bit about 48 hours for propagation...

Comment: Thanks for the response. This is what I get for using shared hosting up until this point ;) I'm aware of the use of A records, was just hoping I didn't have to as my provider doesn't quite "work".

Comment: @Enstage - I have my domain with NameCheap, and all I had to do to use Amazon as my DNS was copy four DNS addresses that the Route53 panel gave me, and paste them into the appropriate fields in the NameCheap control panel. And then of course, add an `A record` on the Route53 control panel pointing to my EC2's IP address.

Comment: Well there are many ways of managing a domain name. If OP requires only the website to be accessible, he can simply do an `A` record over his domain registrar's login panel while leaving the `NS` untouched. As for Google DNS, of course, OP can simply configure name-servers within the VPS which is another thing.